# My Script is not working in Chrome and Firefox (Mac) but works in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-browser

Any Help with this would be appreciated. My script seems to work in Safari but doesn't work on any other browser? I'm at a loss as I am very novice with Jquery and parsing. Thanks!

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      /* Edit these variables */
      var api = "66ffde1312******";
      var state = "TX";
      var city = "Dallas";

      $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + api + "/conditions/q/" + state + "/" + city + ".json",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
          var icon_url_json = "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/f/" + parsed_json['current_observation']['icon'] + ".gif";
          var icon_json = '<img src ="' + icon_url_json + '" />';
          var temp_json = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
            temp_json += "<span>°F</span>";
          var condition_json = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
          var real_feel_json = "Feels Like " + parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_f'] + "°F";
          var wind_json = 'Winds are ' + parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_string'];
          var location_json = city + ', ' + state;

      document.getElementById("weather-icon").innerHTML = icon_json;
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = temp_json;
      document.getElementById("condition").innerHTML = condition_json;  
      document.getElementById("real-feel").innerHTML = real_feel_json;
      document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = wind_json;
      document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = location_json;
      }
      });
    });
```

and the html:

```
    <div class = "weather">
      <div id = "weather-icon"></div>
      <div class = "text-container">
        <p id = "condition"></p>
        <p id = "temp"></p>
        <p id = "real-feel"></p>
        <p id="wind"></p>
        <p id="location"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to debug in Chrome and find out at which exact line it is breaking. On chrome you can press F12 to see the error in console. Before that maybe try commenting out the weather icon div setting inner html that seems a bit odd to me.